# Unable to start mysql server after update

Tags: mysql, apparmor

Today I updated the system, and I cant start the mysql server:

I'm getting the following error:

```
Aug 14 14:32:09 VULTURUS kernel: [ 1996.413190] init: mysql main process (14122) terminated with status 1
Aug 14 14:32:09 VULTURUS kernel: [ 1996.413262] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Aug 14 14:32:10 VULTURUS kernel: [ 1997.373479] init: mysql post-start process (14123) terminated with status 1
Aug 14 14:32:10 VULTURUS kernel: [ 1997.391012] type=1400 audit(1344947530.964:242): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=14156 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 14 14:32:11 VULTURUS kernel: [ 1997.453824] type=1400 audit(1344947531.028:243): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/WESYS_DATA/MySql_LX/" pid=14160 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=115 ouid=0
Aug 14 14:32:11 VULTURUS kernel: [ 1997.456707] init: mysql main process (14160) terminated with status 1
Aug 14 14:32:11 VULTURUS kernel: [ 1997.456775] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

But I already added the exception in the /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
# Last Modified: Tue Jun 19 17:37:30 2007
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/sbin/mysqld {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>
  #include <abstractions/user-tmp>
  #include <abstractions/mysql>
  #include <abstractions/winbind>

  capability dac_override,
  capability sys_resource,
  capability setgid,
  capability setuid,

  network tcp,

  /etc/hosts.allow r,
  /etc/hosts.deny r,

  /etc/mysql/*.pem r,
  /etc/mysql/conf.d/ r,
  /etc/mysql/conf.d/* r,
  /etc/mysql/*.cnf r,
  /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ r,
  /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/*.so* mr,
  /usr/sbin/mysqld mr,
  /usr/share/mysql/** r,
  /var/log/mysql.log rw,
  /var/log/mysql.err rw,
  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
  /var/log/mysql/ r,
  /var/log/mysql/* rw,
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid w,
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,
  /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid w,
  /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,

  /sys/devices/system/cpu/ r,

  /media/WESYS_DATA/MySql_LX/** rwk,
  /media/WESYS_DATA/MySql_LX/** rwk,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/usr.sbin.mysqld>
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following two lines in the **/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld** overlap.

```
/media/WESYS_DATA/MySql_LX/** rwk,
/media/WESYS_DATA/MySql_LX/** rwk,
```

When you replace these lines to the below lines, your problem may be solved.

```
/media/WESYS_DATA/MySql_LX/ r,
/media/WESYS_DATA/MySql_LX/** rwk,
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the message:

```
mysql respawning too fast
```

I found in the `syslog` that this was there because I had done a remove of apparmor, but had forgotten to restart my server.

After a reboot of my server, mysql started fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case during Ubuntu update from 11.04 to 11.10 endless cycle occurred (and installation did not go on):

```
Sep 24 21:50:05 soft kernel: [ 4926.795768] type=1400 audit(1380048605.174:160):     apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=10215    comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 24 21:50:05 soft kernel: [ 4926.954977] type=1400 audit(1380048605.334:161): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/srv/mysql/soft.lower-test" pid=10219 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Sep 24 21:50:05 soft kernel: [ 4926.955011] type=1400 audit(1380048605.334:162): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/srv/mysql/soft.lower-test" pid=10219 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Sep 24 21:50:05 soft kernel: [ 4927.043602] type=1400 audit(1380048605.424:163): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/srv/mysql/mysql/plugin.frm" pid=10219 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=102 ouid=102
Sep 24 21:50:05 soft kernel: [ 4927.087869] type=1400 audit(1380048605.464:164): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/srv/mysql/ibdata1" pid=10219 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="rw" denied_mask="rw" fsuid=102 ouid=102
Sep 24 21:50:05 soft init: mysql main process (10219) terminated with status 1
```

Solution: I logged in in separate window and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Then followed syslog and noticed that install continued normallly.

Comment: The "stop" command worked for me when my do-release-upgrade from utopic to vivid hung with similar messages in syslog.  No idea if it hurt the mysql upgrade, but if it did I'll deal with that problem later...

Answer (score 0):

I've got the error, after enabling queries slow-log. It turns out, variable name from `mysqld.conf` template has changed from `log_slow_queries`, and now it should be

`slow-query-log-file = /var/log...`

Thanks to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1610765/comments/35