# Ubuntu 16.04 mariaDB not working after update

Tags: upgrade, updates, mysql, database, mariadb

I have mariaDB on remote server, Whenever i type `mysql -u root -p` it throws :

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

And on `service mysql start` it throws :

`Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

It happened it self because of update or upgrade.

I am using mariadb so the `/etc/mysql` folder have :

```
conf.d  
debian.cnf
debian-start
mariadb.conf.d
my.cnf
my.cnf.fallback
my.cnf.save
mysql.cnf
mysql.conf.d
```

**Updated :**

`systemctl status mysql.service` Returns :

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-06-11 08:23:54 UTC; 14s ago
  Process: 30388 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 30380 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30388 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 30391 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 324.0K
      CPU: 356ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─30391 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─30475 sleep 1

Jun 11 08:23:54 demo systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jun 11 08:23:54 demo systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

`journalctl -xe` Returns :

```
Jun 11 08:28:14 demo sshd[31141]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=114.115.215.178  user=www-data
Jun 11 08:28:16 demo sshd[31143]: Failed password for root from 59.63.188.32 port 52862 ssh2
Jun 11 08:28:16 demo sshd[31141]: Failed password for www-data from 114.115.215.178 port 44506 ssh2
Jun 11 08:28:19 demo sshd[31143]: Failed password for root from 59.63.188.32 port 52862 ssh2
Jun 11 08:28:19 demo sshd[31141]: Failed password for www-data from 114.115.215.178 port 44506 ssh2
Jun 11 08:28:21 demo sshd[31141]: Failed password for www-data from 114.115.215.178 port 44506 ssh2
Jun 11 08:28:21 demo sshd[31143]: Failed password for root from 59.63.188.32 port 52862 ssh2
Jun 11 08:28:21 demo sshd[31141]: Connection closed by 114.115.215.178 port 44506 [preauth]
Jun 11 08:28:21 demo sshd[31141]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=114.115.215.178  user=www-data
Jun 11 08:28:22 demo sshd[31143]: Received disconnect from 59.63.188.32 port 52862:11:  [preauth]
Jun 11 08:28:22 demo sshd[31143]: Disconnected from 59.63.188.32 port 52862 [preauth]
Jun 11 08:28:22 demo sshd[31143]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=59.63.188.32  user=root
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1497169714.604:4579): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/31200/status" pid=31
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo audit[31200]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/31200/status" pid=31200 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo audit[31200]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=31200 comm="mysqld" requested_
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo audit[31200]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/31200/status" pid=31200 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1497169714.608:4580): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/"
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1497169714.608:4581): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/31200/status" pid=31
Jun 11 08:28:34 demo systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Comment: Did you *"See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details"*? if so, what did they show?

Comment: @steeldriver I have updated my question. I showed out of  `systemctl status mysql.service` and `journalctl -xe`.

Comment: Hmm... looks similar to [Unable to start mysql server after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175704/unable-to-start-mysql-server-after-update) - maybe check your apparmor mysql configuration?

Comment: There is nothing i got. Things seems fine to me ! Whats next ?

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue with MariaDB after upgrade from Ubuntu 18 LTS to Ubuntu 20 LTS. In my case it was missing collation preventing mysqld to start. Probably because when asked during the upgrade if I want to keep my current (locally modified) configs or want them replaced by up-to-date ones, I always kept locals. So probably that's how the new required value didn't make it there.

Anyway, this is how I found out:

```
mysqld --help --verbose | grep 'log-error' | tail -1
```

This showed me the error that `[ERROR] COLLATION 'utf8mb4_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'`. So I opened mysql config:

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

There I added `collation-server` line to the very bottom (based on [this Stack Overflow reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28117297/14155799)). So my config looked like this:

```
...

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
```

Then I restarted the service and voila, mysqld is up again:

```
sudo service mysqld start
```